# How to see all filters added with 'tc filter add ...'?

Tags: filter, iptables

I want to drop output packets on wlan0 device of router with 'busybox', 'Linux version 2.6.30.9 ', 'tc utility, iproute2-ss060323', 'iptables v1.3.5'.

1. What I do:

   ## commands to create qdisc hierarchy:

   tc qdisc add dev wlan0 root handle 1: htb default 0
   tc class add dev wlan0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 3mbit ceil 3mbit burst 15k
   tc class add dev wlan0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 100kbps ceil 100kbps burst 15k
   tc class add dev wlan0 parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate 84kbps ceil 84kbps burst 15k
   tc class add dev wlan0 parent 1:1 classid 1:30 htb rate 200kbps ceil 200kbps burst 15k
   tc qdisc add dev wlan0 parent 1:10 pfifo
   tc qdisc add dev wlan0 parent 1:20 pfifo
   tc qdisc add dev wlan0 parent 1:30 pfifo

## check packet statistics as you see no one packet was got in 1:10,1:20,1:30 classes

```
# tc -s -d qdisc show dev wlan0
qdisc htb 1: r2q 10 default 0 direct_packets_stat 3252 ver 3.17
 Sent 4494542 bytes 3262 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc pfifo 8001: parent 1:10 [Unknown qdisc, optlen=4] 
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc pfifo 8002: parent 1:20 [Unknown qdisc, optlen=4] 
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc pfifo 8003: parent 1:30 [Unknown qdisc, optlen=4] 
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

## added filters to direct traffic  in 1:30 class with speed limit.

## I hope these filters catch all traffic going to my laptop with 192.168.1.202 ip.

```
tc filter add dev wlan0 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip src 192.168.1.202/32 classid 1:30
tc filter add dev wlan0 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 2 u32 match ip dst 192.168.1.202/32 classid 1:30
```

## lets check statistics

## As you see 1:30 class got less kilo bytes but at the same time I tried to download with my laptop 10 mega bytes

## I.e. two added filters did not catch all traffic from router to my laptop.

```
# tc -s -d qdisc show dev wlan0
qdisc htb 1: r2q 10 default 0 direct_packets_stat 9754 ver 3.17
 Sent 14208062 bytes 9928 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc pfifo 8001: parent 1:10 [Unknown qdisc, optlen=4] 
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc pfifo 8002: parent 1:20 [Unknown qdisc, optlen=4] 
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc pfifo 8003: parent 1:30 [Unknown qdisc, optlen=4] 
 Sent 26713 bytes 164 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

## delete filters and add new filter

```
tc filter del dev wlan0 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 1 u32 match ip src 192.168.1.202/32 classid 1:30
tc filter del dev wlan0 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 2 u32 match ip dst 192.168.1.202/32 classid 1:30
tc filter add dev wlan0 parent 1:0 protocol ip prio 50 u32 match ip src 0.0.0.0/0 flowid 1:30
```

## lets check statistics

## You see dropped packets in class 1:30, also I tried to download with wget and had only 200kbps speed.

## I.e. last added filter works and direct all traffic to class 1:30

```
# tc -s -d qdisc show dev wlan0
qdisc htb 1: r2q 10 default 0 direct_packets_stat 9796 ver 3.17
 Sent 25807228 bytes 17790 pkt (dropped 276, overlimits 9955 requeues 0) 
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc pfifo 8001: parent 1:10 [Unknown qdisc, optlen=4] 
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc pfifo 8002: parent 1:20 [Unknown qdisc, optlen=4] 
 Sent 0 bytes 0 pkt (dropped 0, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0 
qdisc pfifo 8003: parent 1:30 [Unknown qdisc, optlen=4] 
 Sent 11616972 bytes 7984 pkt (dropped 276, overlimits 0 requeues 0) 
 rate 0bit 0pps backlog 0b 0p requeues 0
```

2, WHat i got?
    I can filter all traffic and direct it to class 1:30 with speed limit.
    I cant filter WGET traffic from router to my laptop.
3. Questions : 
    How to create filter that catcth ONLY traffic from router to my laptop in class 1:30?
    How to see all filters added with 'tc filter add ...'?

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
tc filter add dev wlan0 parent 10:0 protocol ip prio 50 u32 \ 
  match ip dst 192.168.1.202 flowid 10:1
```

Where `10:1` is the classid of qdisc.

To view statistics of filters:

```
tc -s -d filter show dev wlan0 egress
```

Answer (score 0):

The title reads as if you want to see all filter rules for all interfaces.
No way to do this with tc directly, need to build each tc filter command associated with an interface name. Here is a one liner to perform a `tc filter show` on all interfaces on your system:

```
for i in $(ip -br a | awk '{print$1}'); do echo "### $i ###";tc filter show dev $i ingress 2>/dev/null; done
```

Note adjust `ingress` to which ever pattern you want. You could also create a bash array with `a=(ingress root egress)` and loop through that as well.